# Commands out of sync you can't run this command now QMYSQL unable to execute query

Tags: mariadb

I'm using MariaDB version 10.5.9.0, the application I'm writing is using MSVC 2015 with Qt 5.9.2

Today I am seeing an error from the database when I try to execute one of my stored procedures, the procedure hasn't changed and has been working without any issues for quite a while.

The error displayed is:

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now QMYSQL: Unable to execute query
```

Yet, despite this error the stored procedure works and the data is added to the database.

I've tried selecting everything in the database using HeidiSQL then using the Tools > Maintenance, Check then Analyse, the Repair and finally Optimize

Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the issue was calling **QSqlQuery** and then another subquery using **QSqlQuery** again without calling **clear** on the first query.

Comment: That's bad style: you should always process subsequent result sets: they might contain more result sets, error packages or status changes which will be skipped when clearing all results.